# How to read in user inputs to create objects?

Tags: java, arrays, input

I'm pretty new to Java still and I'm working on a project for class, and I'm unsure of how I write my program to take the userInput(fileName) and create a new object from that. My instructions are to write a program which reads in a file name from the user and then reads the data from that file, creates objects(type StudentInvoice) and stores them in an ArrayList.

This is where I am right now.

```
    public class StudentInvoiceListApp {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName;

    System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
    fileName = userInput.nextLine();

    ArrayList<StudentInvoice> invoiceList = new ArrayList<StudentInvoice>();
    invoiceList.add(new StudentInvoice());
    System.out.print(invoiceList + "\n");

    }
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question. For example, what does the input file look like? You might be better off asking a more specific question about where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to write a class for **serializing / deserializing** objects from a stream (see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) article).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Robert said, there's not enough information about the format of the data stored in the file. Suppose each line of the file contains all the information for a student. Your program will consist of reading a file by lines and create a StudentInvoice for each line. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<StudentInvoice> studentInvoices = new ArrayList<StudentInvoice>();
    String line, filename;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter data file: ");
        filename = userInput.nextLine();
    } while (filename == null);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        studentInvoices.add(new StudentInvoice(line));
    }

    System.out.println("Total student invoices: " + studentInvoices.size());
}
```